# Bash function can't return large numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, cluster-computing

I wrote the following bash script:

```
function getqsubnumber {
# Return how many simulations ($qsubnumber) are currently running

qsubnumber=`qstat | grep p00 | wc -l`

return $qsubnumber
}


getqsubnumber
qs=$?

if [ $qs -le $X ]
    then
        echo 'Running one more simulation'
        $cmd # submit one more job to the cluster
else
    echo 'Too many simulations running ... Sleeping for 2 min'
    sleep 120
```

The idea is that I am submitting jobs on a cluster. If there are more than `X` jobs running at the same time, I want to wait for 2 minutes.

The code works for `X=50` and for `X=200`. For some unknown reason, it doesn't work for `X=400`. Any idea why? The script never wait for 2 minutes, it keeps on submitting jobs.

Comment: That's not how return values in functions are used, see the duplicate.

Comment: Hmm, might not be the best dupe target, but it's [BashFAQ/84](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/084).

Comment: I tried to write `echo` instead of return (keeping everything else the same), it didn't work @BenjaminW.

Comment: You have to use `gs=$(getqsubnumber)`.

Comment: it worked ! thanks :)

Comment: Tangentially, `grep | wc -l` is better written `grep -c` -- see also [useless use of `wc -l`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return values of Unix processes (and a shell function acts like one) can be only in the range of a single byte, i. e. 0…255 (in some contexts the range is -128…+127).

To return values in larger ranges I propose to use the stdout as a channel to provide the result:

```
function getqsubnumber {
  # Return how many simulations ($qsubnumber) are currently running
  qstat | grep p00 | wc -l
}

qs=$(getqsubnumber)
```

Comment: why note use `echo` as what is suggested in @Benjamin's link?

Comment: `echo` writes something to stdout.  So do many other programs, e. g. `wc`.  You can capture the output of `wc` (`x=$(… | wc -l)`) and then print it again to stdout using `echo` (`echo "$x"`).  But the result will be the same as if you hadn't captured it and instead had allowed it to be written to stdout in the first place ;-)

Comment: one more question since I am new to coding in bash, what are the parenthesis for? Does `qs=$getqsubnumber` work? (I just reran my script, so I cannot test it now!)

Comment: The dollar-parentheses operator is the modern variant of the backquotes (which are discouraged by now), so they are replaced by the output of the command within the parentheses.  `qs=$getqsubnumber` would try to find a _variable_ named `getqsubnumber` and would be replaced by the variable's value (but there isn't one in this context, so it would result in setting `qs` to an empty string).

Comment: These are basic FAQs.  See [useless use of backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#backticks) and "useless use of `echo`" on the same page, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash ... More generally, you (the OP) might want to check out the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) for these basic questions.

Comment: (Looking up such links is always more work for me than simply answering the questions at hand, but the links are probably more useful in the long run.)